# fopen multiple files in php

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I'm trying to make my PHP script open more than 1 text document and to read them.

My current script is as follows:

```html
<?php
 //$searchthis = "ignore this";
 $matches = array();
 $FileW = fopen('result.txt', 'w');
 $handle = @fopen("textfile1.txt", "r");
 ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
 if ($handle)
 {
  while (!feof($handle))
  {
   $buffer = fgets($handle);
   if(stripos($buffer, $_POST["search"]) !== FALSE)
    $matches[] = $buffer;
  }
  fwrite($FileW, print_r($matches, TRUE));
  fclose($handle);
 }
?>
```

I'm trying to fopen like a bunch of files, maybe like 8 of them or less.

How would I open, and read all these files?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Stop doing `@fopen`, the `@` suppresses any errors there may be - and with `fopen`, errors are common and important. What have you tried on your own?

Comment: I guess I didn't need it there. No errors what so ever. I'm just curious on how I can open multiple files / read them in one variable.

Comment: so, I know I can't do this but I'd be something like:
$multiplefiles = fopen("textfile1.txt", "textfile2.txt", "textfile3.txt", "r");
now obviously you cant do that due to the fopen parameters but is there an alternative way to do it?

Comment: Sure. Put your `fopen`/`fclose` calls in a foreach loop against a list of files. Hardly complex.

Answer (score 0):

Program defensively, check the return's from functions to ensure you are not making incorrect assumptions about your code.

There is a function in PHP to read the file and buffer it:

[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to open a lot of files, it surely will use a lot of memory, anyway, you could use the `file_get_contents` function with a `foreach`:

```
$files = array("textfile1.txt", "textfile2.txt", "textfile3.txt");

$data = "";
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $data .= @file_get_contents($file);
}

echo $data;
```

Comment: didn't think of having it in an array. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in php called `file` which reads entire file into an array.

```
<?php

    // "file" function creates array with each line being 1 value to an array

    $fileOne = file('fileOne.txt'); 
    $fileTwo = file('fileTwo.txt');

   // Print an array or do all array magic with $fileOne and $fileTwo
    foreach($fileOne as $fo) {
        echo $fo;
    }

    foreach($fileTwo as $ft) {
        $echo $ft;
    }
?>
```

Read more about : [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function ion php