# Exporting extracted mp4 links to a new txt file in PHP

Tags: php, file, hyperlink, mp4, fopen

I have this php code which extract specific mp4 links from a txt file called SSIPTVx.txt.

My question is: how a i can export the obtained results to a New txt file?

```
<?php
// Open txt file
$file = fopen("SSIPTVx.txt", "r");

// Read the content line by line
while(!feof($file)) {
  $line = fgets($file);


// Find specific .mp4 links
  preg_match_all('/(https?:\/\/(tream720\.xyz\/content\/|nvid101\.cdnii\.com\/|video\.videodomain\.icu\/)[^\s]+\.mp4)/', $line, $matches);

// Print found links
  foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    echo $match . "<br>";
  }

}

// Close txt file
fclose($file);

?>
```

I tried put fopen for a new txt file but i can't obtain any results

Comment: I think this is the way you should do it -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/37780448/9739794
You can't open multiple files at the same time with fopen().

Comment: If file is not huge, maybe use `file_get_contents` & `file_put_contents`, something like [this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##jVJNb4MwDL3nV1gUqaBVhHaTJrVde91ulTrtskwohVCikgRBaOk@fjsLULa2l@3k2H7PfrGdJVldz5erxxVCGEOqaAQxTxmy41yJoHkGkgoGD2Ct10@r55fK05W2ZsjW6jItjoHI7oKUy11h8mhgt@lQSc2kNojW3TLdhwrnqok7a0VETCiIqKbouoKVaJ0VU4x1zqi4n/hedXzHpzzepHTsGQlE/gWb/A9228Car9g527LKCBjilrOcEkyws5z2TNJQSc8l@FPueTT2x8QLI8m5MUqYqAkyRbzWREpQLonHw5Jgl6xvSNMND7sZ8BgODBK6ZyCoDhNWIB47mdERtH5A09TpZI3gYkzGPTFcWIDvog8EYDfjNPq5yFIVMceab/KF9Qt99d@a4QOY1sYPd3BUZd4tAWBP8yAqRea0ZX6Ah5xrBlp1WMkO3eUADFo9WXm@6fNrGUFf6AvV9Tc).